# Combine multiple arbitrary annotations in one

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, jackson

In my code, I'm going to have lots of getters like this with the same set of annotations (one for Hibernate and others for Jackson):

```
@Transient
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = BaseEntity.JSON_DATETIME_FORMAT)
public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateDT() {
    return DateTimeUtils.klabTimestampToLocalDateTime(getCreatedDate(), createdDateDT);
}
```

I want to minimize repetion by implementing my own annotation, which will mean all these four together, like this:

```
@TransientLocalDateTime
public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateDT() {
    return DateTimeUtils.klabTimestampToLocalDateTime(getCreatedDate(), createdDateDT);
}
```

How can I do it? Is this even possible?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Konstantin Yovkov, now I know, that I can combine all Jackson annotations in one, but that is because Jackson's annotation processor recognizes such a trick. I wonder if it is possible to make *any* annotation processor do that? It seems to me that it's not.

Answer (score 10):

Jackson provides a meta-annotation (annotation used for annotating another annotation), called [`@JacksonAnnotationsInside`](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.3.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotationsInside.html), which is a:

> Meta-annotation (annotations used on other annotations) used for
>   indicating that instead of using target annotation (annotation
>   annotated with this annotation), Jackson should use meta-annotations
>   it has.
>
> This can be useful in creating "combo-annotations" by having a
>   container annotation, which needs to be annotated with this annotation
>   as well as all annotations it 'contains'.

So, you should create an annotation like this one:

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD,
                  ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside // <-- this one is mandatory
@Transient
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = BaseEntity.JSON_DATETIME_FORMAT)
public @interface TransientLocalDateTime {    
}
```

and use is like:

```
@TransientLocalDateTime
public LocalDateTime getCreatedDateDT() {
    return DateTimeUtils.klabTimestampToLocalDateTime(getCreatedDate(), createdDateDT);
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but can it be used for arbitrary annotations or for Jackson's annotations only? It seems `@Transient` is not allowed here.

Comment: I can be used for arbitrary annotations, but can only be processed by the Jackson annotation processor ... unless you write a custom annotation processor, but then I believe you could just introduce a brand new annotation (and not use `@JacksonAnnotationsInside `), which is processed by your annotation processor.

Comment: Also, I get `@TransientLocalDateTime not applicable to method` error in my IDE.

Comment: For the latter error, just set it with `@Target(value = { ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })` to be able to use it on every possible element.